# dropping database created by entity framework

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, t-sql

In SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio I have tried to remove my old training databases, created during my entity framework entertainment.
To do so I tried to just delete them by "right-click" and "delete",

but I get message:

> Could not retrieve database access level for database

After creating new query "DROP DATABASE ...;"

I receive answer

> Cannot drop the database '...', because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

Any other way to remove it, or just getting permission?

Comment: are you logged in as a sql server admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution :

1. Close your solution.
2. Then exit from the Visual studio.
3. After that reopen your project with new instance of Visual studio.

Hope all are fine then :)

Comment: Miracle! Despite refusing dropping operation by Visual Studio, It actually got performed after restarting visual studio! <br/>

Comment: Hehee... :D Restart is an invaluable weapon on Microsoft products :D